# ¿Como agregar una regla de validacion personalizada en laravel?

Tags: laravel, validación

quisiera saber si es posible que en una validacion de laravel agregarle por ejemplo una propiedad personalizada para una consulta, por ejemplo :

```php
 public function rules(): array
    {
         $registros = Registro::all()
         ->where("departamento_id",1)
         ->where("cod_doc",codigo LLegado);
          //Si esto es correcto existe un registro con el mismo codigo 
          //por lo cual hay falla en la validacion y devuelve el mensaje
          
          //Ahora bien,porque no uso "unique", y resulta que todos aquellos registros
          //Estan guardados en una tabla llamado "registros" y quiero filtrar y producirles
          //una consulta en el cual solo se produzca determinada accion si son de un 
          //determinado departamento,en el cual tendra un campo simulado "unico" a cada
          //registro que en este caso es "cod_doc" que permanezca a un determinado 
           //departamento
          //y con la propiedad unique no podría ya que se produciria en todos los 
          //departamentos determinada accion
        return [
            'cod_doc' => "required|valorPersonalizado|max:9",
            "materia" => "required",
            "asignacion" => "required"

        ];
    }
```

En caso de que esa propiedad me devuelva o no un valor hacer una determinada accion,es eso,ahora bien , si hay una mejor solución o no está bien planteada mi pregunta, haganmelo saber y lo editare,gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Ya encontre la forma , simplemente tenía que crear una nueva Rule , e indicar mi filtro, pongo código en caso de que a alguien más le ayude!

Paso 1: Crear una nueva rule

```php
php artisan make:rule ExampleRule
```

Paso 2 : Indicar tu condicion para validar determinado campo

```php
  public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        //
        return  Registro::where("departamento_id",1)->where("cod_doc",$value)->count() == 0;
    }
```

Paso 3: Finalmente se lo pasas a tu metodo validate

```php
  $request->validate([
            "cod_doc" => ["required",new ExampleRule],
            "materia" => "required",
            "asignacion" => "required"
        ]);
```